# Javascript/html Submit form with return key?

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I have a form which performs a javascript when submit is clicked. I can't seem to figure out how to do the same thing when the return key (13) is used.

HTML: (note MakeRequest() is a JS method which performs a request on another php page and returns results to JSresult.)

```
<form name="SearchForm">
Name: <input type = "text" name = "Name" id="Search"
placeholder="Search stuff here...">
<button type="button" id "Request" onClick="MakeRequest()"">Search</button>

</form>
div id="JSresult">
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try using the form's onsubmit event?

Comment: I will try now, someoen just did an answer and it worked... now they have removed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your button with a submit input and move the function to form onSubmit, instead of button onClick :

```
<form name="SearchForm" onSubmit="MakeRequest();">
    Name: <input type = "text" name = "Name" id="Search" placeholder="Search stuff here..." />
    <input type="submit" id="Request" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Comment: Your last answer worked, this current one does not.. on the last answer however, I now receive a button which says Submit Query rather than Search. How do I modify it as it does not say Search Query in any of the code?

Comment: fixed- just added the value tags

Answer (score 0):

Here is an unobtrusive approach that should do the trick:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById("Search").onkeydown = function(e){
            key = (e.keyCode) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
            if(key == 13) {
                document.getElementById("Request").click();
            }
        };
    };
</script>
```

Just copy that into the `head` of your HTML file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although my question has been answered already, this gives me another excellent approach to this!